# ng-repeat not showing up in ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I use an ng-repeat to display cards, tinder-style. The cards are loaded from a controller which contacts Firebase to source 100 of said objects in an array.  Everything works as intended, except the cards don't display until I click the menu button on the upper right of the screen.  Then they pop into existence, from not being on the DOM to all of them appearing when I do inspect element.

I'm suspicious it has something to do with the organization of the HTML as set up by ionic, but my googling left my lacking and hoping someone here has had a similar experience.

```html
  <ion-nav-view>
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/cards">
          Cards
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
  </ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to trigger a digest once the data has loaded from firebase. I suspect this because the view updates when you click on something.

Try calling $timeout after the async code that loads the data. You will need to inject it like $scope into that context. $timeout is a trick to trigger digest loops.

Comment: Thanks! $timeout didn't do it, but $scope.$apply() fixed it immediately---you definitely pointed me in the right direction